# Не даёт зайти,ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, plsql-developer

Пытаюсь зайти в PL-SQL Developer,ввожу имя базы, которая на другом компьютере. В итоге выходит следующая ошибка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сразу скажу,что в `TNS`-файле данная база прописана, как и другие базы данных.

```
myDB1 =
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ***айпишник компьютера где находится эта база***)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
       (SERVICE_NAME = myDB1)
    )  
  )
```

То что в `TNS`-файле компьютера, то и в файле клиента.
На главном компьютере база работает и запускается, а на клиенте нет. Служба базы данных запущена.
Как я понял `listener` клиенту не надо создавать, главное чтобы был `tnsnames.ora.`
Перебирал именами было и `myDBB1,myDBDB,myDataBase и myDB` и через точки и пробелы его айпи-адрес,но ошибка так и не исчезла.
Остальные базы на клиентском компьютере работают без проблем.

Comment: PL-SQL Developer не находит файл tnsnames.ora. Как вы ему сообщили, где надо искать?

Comment: @0xdb файл находит в Девелопере,сам файл рабочий,так как с него остальные базы со списка грузятся нормально.

Comment: Значит не находит саму запись. Проверьте, не стоит ли перед  myDB1 пробел или другой непечатный знак.

Comment: @0xdb сейчас проверил на пробелы, данная ошибка исчезла но появилась другая. Код ошибки такой же но содержание другое

ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Мне отдельную тему создать или дополнить своё главное сообщение?

Comment: Теперь запись найдена, но сервис указаный в ней, не существует или не зарегестрирован. Это совсем другая ошибка, поэтому воспользуйтесь поиском здесь на сайте, если не поможет, то задайте новый вопрос.И будте внимательней - _Код ошибки такой же но содержание другое_ - __ORA-12514 != ORA-12154__.